# VFP Application Hangs When Ran as Different User

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am using a Visual FoxPro application on one of my servers. The problem is, when I run the application as a different user, it takes forever to load. When ran as the user that is logged in to the computer, the program loads in less than 3 seconds. But for some reason when I run it as a different user, it takes anywhere from around 30 seconds to 3 minutes just for the application to come up. I can not run this as the logged in user, because the account I use to log into the server cannot be given access to this application. I have also tested the same application on my local machine, and it does not take nearly the amount of time required to launch the program as the server requires, when ran as a different user or not. Sorry if this sounds confusing, if more information is required to help diagnose the problem I will be glad to provide it. The application is using Visual FoxPro 6.0.

Thanks